# kohsuke github api works sometimes but gives no errors when it doesnt

Tags: java, android

So I am running a headles linux system that I want to update from a github repo over bluetooth. So the linux system sends the last commit it found when searching for an update earlier. From that point on the app needs to check for new commits containing srec files in a certain path in the github. This is the code I have:

```
class CompareVersion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CompareVersion: starting to compare version");
            try {
                gitHub = GitHub.connectAnonymously();
                repository = gitHub.getRepository("Public repository");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "compareVersion: unable to connect to github", e);
            }
            if (fileURLs != null) {
                fileURLs.clear();
            }
            for (GHCommit c : repository.queryCommits().since(lastUpdateDate).path("module-firmware").list()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CompareVersion: Commit found");
                try {
                    commitDates.add(c.getCommitDate());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "compareVersion: not able to extract commit date from commit", e);
                }
                List<GHCommit.File> updatedFiles = null;
                try {
                    updatedFiles = c.getFiles();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "compareVersion: not able to get files from commit", e);
                }
                assert updatedFiles != null;
                for (GHCommit.File file : updatedFiles) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: current file: "+ file.getFileName());
                    if (file.getFileName().contains("srec")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: srec file found: "+ file.getFileName());
                        fileURLs.add(file.getRawUrl().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (fileURLs.size() > 0) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new CompareVersionComplete());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now this morning I started it up for the first time and it worked mostly. I saw that it found commits and files.

But then when I rebuild after some small changes to fix some other things, not changing this code whatsoever it stops working.

The weird thing is it doesnt give any errors but when i try to print anything from the github or repository it just does nothing. No error and nothing else.

But i do see it logging the "starting to compare version" logd.

I just dont know whats going wrong.

Logcat from the compare version message on:

2022-03-21 09:31:21.577 4620-4759/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration D/MainActivity: CompareVersion: starting to compare version

2022-03-21 09:31:21.581 4620-4620/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration D/ColorViewRootUtil: initSwipState, isDisplayCompatApp false

2022-03-21 09:31:21.581 4620-4620/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration D/ColorViewRootUtil: updateScreenSize, mScreenHeight 2400,mScreenWidth:1080,height:2400,width:1080

2022-03-21 09:31:21.732 4620-4759/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

2022-03-21 09:31:21.734 4620-4759/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar

2022-03-21 09:31:21.754 4620-4759/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar

2022-03-21 09:31:23.497 4620-4653/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x6f9b1c9000,api=1)

2022-03-21 09:31:23.499 4620-4620/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = com.color.internal.widget.ColorToastLayout{a83a26a V.E...... ......ID 0,0-545,105 #c0204f9 oppo:id/color_toast_layout}

2022-03-21 09:31:23.500 4620-4620/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration I/InputTransport: Destroy ARC handle: 0x6f9af36360

2022-03-21 09:31:23.540 4620-4620/com.example.gocontrolconfiguration I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the .connectAnonymously method, apparently it is not recommended for use, changed it to connect with an auth token and then it worked fine.